# How to substitute a value into a form field from a database

Tags: python, django

I have related models; when they are saved, some data is saved in the first model, others in the second. Now I'm trying to update the data so that when a button is pressed, the data from the two models is updated since the fields in the form 'client_name' and 'phones' are not connected to anything, I partially achieved this, they are updated and saved, but when the form is opened, the fields 'client_name', 'phones', I need to somehow substitute previously saved values ​​into these fields so that they can be edited in the field.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.


class Person(models.Model):
    client_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Фио клиента')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.client_name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Клиент'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Клиенты'


class Phone(models.Model):
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Телефон')
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='phones', verbose_name='Контакт', null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.phone

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Телефон'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Телефоны'


class Orders(models.Model):  # Основная база данных
    objects = None
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, verbose_name='Принял', blank=True)
    date_of_creation = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='Дата создания')
    execution_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='Дата исполнения')
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Адрес')
    service = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Услуга')
    master = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='master',  null=True, verbose_name='Мастер', blank=True)
    client = models.ForeignKey(Phone, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='client',  null=True, verbose_name='Клиент', blank=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s %s' % (self.execution_date, self.address, self.service)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Заявка'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Заявки'
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Orders, Person, Phone
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserFullnameChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):  # Вывод полного имени и фамилии пользователя
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj.get_full_name()


class OrdersForms(forms.ModelForm):
    master = UserFullnameChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all(), label='Мастер')
    client_name = forms.CharField(label='Фио клиента')
    phones = forms.CharField(label='Телефон')

    class Meta:
        model = Orders
        fields = ('execution_date', 'address', 'service', 'master', 'client_name', 'phones')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['master'].empty_label = '-Выберите мастера-'
        for field in self.fields:
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'


class PhoneForms(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Phone
        fields = ('phone', 'contact')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields:
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'


class AuthUserForm(AuthenticationForm, forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields:
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'


class RegisterUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password', 'groups')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields:
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
            if hasattr(self, "save_m2m"):
                self.save_m2m()
        return user
```

views.py

```
from .models import Orders, Person, Phone
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from .forms import OrdersForms, AuthUserForm, RegisterUserForm, PhoneForms
from django.urls import reverse, reverse_lazy
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView, LogoutView
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect


class OrderCreateView(CustomSuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    model = Orders
    template_name = 'create.html'
    form_class = OrdersForms
    success_url = reverse_lazy('data_base')
    success_msg = 'Заявка дабавлена'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)

        name = self.request.POST.get('client_name')
        phone_number = self.request.POST.get('phones')
        new_person = Person(client_name=name)
        new_person.save()

        person_id = new_person.id
        new_phone = Phone(phone=phone_number, contact_id=person_id)
        new_phone.save()

        phone_id = new_phone.id
        self.object.author = self.request.user
        self.object.client_id = phone_id
        self.object.save()

        # new_person = Person.objects.create(client_name=name)
        # Phone.objects.create(phone=phone_number, contact_id=person_id)
        return super().form_valid(form)


class OrderUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CustomSuccessMessageMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Orders
    template_name = 'edit.html'
    form_class = OrdersForms
    second_form_class = PhoneForms
    success_url = reverse_lazy('edit')
    success_msg = 'Заявка изменена'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)

        name = self.request.POST.get('client_name')
        phone_number = self.request.POST.get('phones')
        new_person = Person(client_name=name)
        new_person.save()

        person_id = new_person.id
        new_phone = Phone(phone=phone_number, contact_id=person_id)
        new_phone.save()

        phone_id = new_phone.id
        self.object.client_id = phone_id
        self.object.save()

        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['update_true'] = True
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        group = self.request.user.groups.all()
        lst_group = [i['name'] for i in group.values()]
        # if self.request.user != kwargs['instance'].author:
        if 'Менеджер' not in lst_group:
        # if str(kwargs['instance'].author.groups.get()) != 'Менеджер':
             return self.handle_no_permission()
        return kwargs
```

Simply put, you need to add something to the OrderUpdateView class so that values ​​from the associated models 'Person' and 'Phone' are inserted into the fields 'client_name', 'phones' from the OrdersForms class.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is, you need to overwrite the `.save` method on your `OrdersForm`, like you did with `RegisterUserForm`.

```py
    def save(self, commit=True):
        obj = super().save(commit=False)

        # First create a person, and store on commit
        person = Person(client_name=self.cleaned_data['client_name'])
        if commit:
            person.save()

        # Second create the phone, with the person. Phone can only be saved
        # if person is saved
        phones = Phone(
            phone=self.cleaned_data['phones'], contact=person
        )
        if commit:
            phones.save()

        # Now we can savely set client, and also save, as required objs
        # have been created
        obj.client = phone
        if commit:
            obj.save()

        return obj
```

Some other generic tips:

- Use the same variables name within your data model. A `Person` is called a `contact` on `Phone`. An `Phone` is called `client` on `Orders`. This was quite confusing while typing the example. Also, I personally like model names to be singular, so `Order`.
- Look into `fields_for_model`, can be found: `from django.forms.models import fields_for_model`. This would be used in `__init__`. So something like `self.fields.update(fields_for_model(Person, fields=['client_name']))`. The benefit is also takes over `max_length`, which can now give you issues if you try to store the order.
- If you want initials to be set. Improve the `__init__`, add something like `self.fields['client_name'] = self.instance.client.contact.client_name`.
- I don't really understand the `objects = None` on `Orders`. What does this do? (This is a genuine question, I never saw it before and I'm interested in features I don't know)

This is a method which can add from another model to your form.

And now I just better read your `OrderUpdateView`, you already did the stuff I said... Lol.. Take the change if you want to. BTW, if it's an update, you need to check if `Orders` already has a `client` set, before creating a new object.

The answer you're looking for is probably the third generic tip. Pay attention `client` can be `None`, so add an `if`.

---

I've expand my answer with how to set initial data on your `OrdersForm`.

```py
class OrdersForm(forms.ModelForm):
    master = UserFullnameChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all(), label='Мастер')
    client_name = forms.CharField(label='Фио клиента')
    phones = forms.CharField(label='Телефон')

    class Meta:
        model = Orders
        fields = ('execution_date', 'address', 'service', 'master', 'client_name', 'phones')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['master'].empty_label = '-Выберите мастера-'
        for field in self.fields:
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'

        if self.instance.client:
            self.fields['client_name'].initial = self.instance.client.contact.client_name
            self.fields['phones'].initial = self.instance.client.phone
```

Comment: Thanks for the interesting solution and valuable advice, but this is not exactly what I was looking for, or I just didn’t understand it correctly. I'm trying to find solutions so that when I click on the 'edit order' button, a window appears with filled fields that can be edited on the spot, but I get a form with filled fields only from the "Orders" model, and two fields "client_name" and "phones" are empty . If you fill them with data and update them, the data will be updated, but I would like, if possible, to insert data into these two fields that I can edit

Comment: I've expand my answer with how to set initial data on your OrdersForm.